# weight loss supplements containing whey protein like slim 24 pro really works?

Tags: supplements

Does weight loss supplements containing whey protein like slim 24 pro really cut down extra inches from your body? need suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Not really, eating more wont help you to lose weight.

There are some studies that suggest that a diet high in protein might be beneficial when trying to lose weight. But to make use of this, you still have to reduce your total caloric intake.
Protein supplements make it easier to reach protein levels that classify as a high-protein diet, but they still count towards your daily caloric intake.

However, supplements are supplements, they should not be used as substitutes for real meals. I would advise always to consume as much protein through your normal diet. Supplements are not inherently bad, but they lack nutrients present in natural food sources. (And cheap supplements might even be contaminated due to bad manufacturing conditions)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't settle for marketing hype. Supplementing with protein is good. I think there are other methods that utilize a program like this too: Herbalife for example has you drink a meal replacement shake which has 20 or so grams of protein in it.

I supplement with protein when i need to meet goals for my macronutrients and calories. Soemtimes it's just easier to make a shake with 30grams of protein than it is to make a cheeseburger, and it's a much cleaner option also...If you are counting calories and monitoring your macros, the protein supplement will help you get that 30-50% protein you're going for without too much extra. If this is not the case, and you are just having a "healthy shake" as a snack in addition to your 3 - 6 squares...well...caloric surplus = bulking.

If you want to lose fat, I would look into possibly altering your lifestyle, instead of supplementing it. Perhaps give intermittent fasting a try, there are different styles to suit your needs, helped me lose 10lbs of fat, and replace with lean muscle mass at 5'6" and 175 lbs. This is in a maintenance phase of 2300 calories a day.

Or, perhaps try to get into a Paleo style of eating with/without supplements, this will help you keep your overall caloric intake low (hard to eat 2000 calories worth of veggies and meat)...if you want to use supplements while on Paleo I see nothing wrong with that, other than it might not be straight Paleo. Play around with your calories and lifestyle changes. See what works best. Best of luck to you!